# I am looking for cylinder head bolt tightening torque specs for a Benz OM651

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, torque

I am currently working on a Benz Vito bus engine and cannot find the engine tightening torques. I have search all over the web for this information with no luck.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! An engine has many parts. Which torque specs are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Apologies, i am looking for cylinder head bolt tightening torque specs

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum thread](https://forums.mercedesclub.org.uk/index.php?threads/head-bolt-settings-om651-mercedes-c220.142352/), the torque values for the OM651 engine head bolts are as follows:

- 1st pass - 15Nm (11 lb-ft)
- 2nd pass - 90°
- 3rd pass - 90°

I'm assuming these bolts are most likely torque to yield bolts, you need to be using new bolts when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue many years ago for an old engine.

The mechanic and I took the bolts and worked out the max allowable loading then took 2/3 of that value.

We also looked at the threads and the material of the head and block then derated that calculated by another 10 or 15%.

The engine ran fine.

Do also consider the head gasket as part of the process - for us is was a copper gasket.

Comment: Will try, and let you know the results